# The third-party DLL works when called from Excel and crashes in the case of call from VisualBasic/C#

Tags: c#, vba, com-interop

I have a number of C++Builder third-party x86 DLLs which are used in an x86 TestDll. The TestDll initializes an external device and tries to connect it (using the third-party DLLs). The TestDll is registered and made com-visible to test it under Excel too. It is called from Excel's VBA and similar Visual Basic .Net code:

```
    Dim test As New TestDLL.TestDLL.Class1

    Dim i As Integer

    i = test.Connect()

    If i = 111 Then
        lbl1.Text = "Connected"
    End If

    If i = 222 Then
        lbl1.Text = "Not connected"
    End If

    If i = 333 Then
        lbl1.Text = "Error!!!"
    End If
```

The reference to the TestDll is added in the Excel and the code successfully Returns "Connected". 
When the same code started from the Windows Forms application it returns "Error!!!".

What I found confusing to me is that in Visual Basic the references on the thidr-party DLLs has a form: C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Interop.ThirdPartyDll...... and when I am adding the reference to it in Excel, it has a form: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ThirdParty\ThirdParty.dll

Answer (score 0):

i would delete the (not working) reference in Visual Basic and replace it by the one from Excel by choosing the file manually.

Another possibility: I know this might not be perfect elegant, but you could call an Excel-Instance from your other VBA and then run the code within the Excel-instance, and therefore use the working files.

Max

Comment: I tried to do it. It automatically adds the reference to the GAC.

Comment: You can remove the reference from GAC and then try again.

Comment: Well, I removed the assemblies from GAC and registered only the DLLs I need (using regsvr32). Excel Shows in references the references on the third-pary dlls as ThPart.DLL, the references in VB Looks like Interop.ThPart.DLL. The installation of the third-party DLLs contains already the interops, but their length is different to the length of the new interops in the bin-Folder. 
And again: in Excel the third-party DLLs are working, in VB - not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have multiple copies of same dll at different locations. You can keep the working copy of the dll and remove rest of all the copies. Add reference of the working copy of the dll.